# making pop up window by using SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Tags: java, swing, applet, jdialog, invokelater

I am writing a turn-based game on the internet. I try to pop up a window that should be in front until the input stream is ready. I created smth like this, but it seems that it does not work.

```
class CustomBlockerDialog extends JDialog {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public CustomBlockerDialog(Frame owner, String text) {
    super(owner, true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 100); // Adjust if needed
    setTitle("");
    add(new JLabel(text, SwingConstants.CENTER));
} 
}




final CustomBlockerDialog block = new CustomBlockerDialog(null, "Not your turn");

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {//A

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("show");
        block.setVisible(true);
    }
});


boolean one_write_only = true;
while(in.ready()){ /* C*/ 
    if(one_write_only){
        System.out.println("waiting server");
        one_write_only = false;
    }
};

System.out.println("suppose to hide");

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {//B

    @Override
    public void run() {
    System.out.println("hide");
    block.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

It looks like "A" and "B" are executed after "C" and I have no idea why.

Comment: Sorry for not posting for sooo long time. I remember about it but i have a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I created a little different solution which works in my case:

```
final SwingWorker<Object,Object> worker2 = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
        public Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
          boolean one_write_only = true;
            while(!in.ready()){ /* C*/ 
              if(one_write_only){
                System.out.println("waiting server");
                one_write_only = false;
              }
            }
            return one_write_only;
        }

        protected void done() {
            try {
                block.setVisible(false);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {}
        }

};
worker2.execute();
block.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem must be due to "C" being called on the Swing event thread and not in a background thread, since it sounds like "C" is blocking the event thread from running "A". Solution: be sure that "C" is not called on the Swing event thread. Also if this is the case, and this can be tested by running the `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` method, then you don't need all those other runnables.

```
// note that this all must be called on the Swing event thread:
final CustomBlockerDialog block = new CustomBlockerDialog(null, "Not your turn");

System.out.println("show");
// block.setVisible(true);  // !! no this will freeze!

final SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<>() {
   public void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      boolean one_write_only = true;
      while(in.ready()){ /* C*/ 
         if(one_write_only){
            System.out.println("waiting server");
            one_write_only = false;
         }
      }
   }
}

worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
   public void propertyChanged(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
      if (pcEvt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
         System.out.println("hide");
         block.setVisible(false);

         // call worker's get() method here and catch exceptions
      }
   }
});

worker.execute();

// moved to down here since the dialog is modal!!!
block.setVisible(true);
```

Caveat: code not compiled nor tested. There may be errors present as it was typed off the cuff.